# zsh: command not found after installing latest version of node with nvm

Tags: node.js, shell, zsh, nvm

After I install the latest version of Node with nvm e.g

```
nvm install 16.13.1
```

I get "command not found" errors in my console e.g

```
ionic capacitor build android --dev
zsh: command not found: ionic
```

If I switch back to using 12.6.2 of Node everything works again.

What do I need to do to get things to work with the latest version?

Comment: Looks like after jumping 4 major versions the ionic executable might be installed in a different directory not in PATH. Or the new directory is not picked up and inserted to `PATH` by your shell startup code. Maybe `find /usr -name ionic` casts some light. Compare that to `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Thanks - I actually fixed this by re-installing ionic cli